# Joining two sublists

Tags: python, arrays

community,

I'm struggling to append the two sublists I have (p and t) extracted from a textfile. The code should be ok up to "print (p,t)", but the append command afterwards does not work (i have also tried output.extend ([p,t])). The lists contain:
p= pronouns (uttered by testpersons)
t=testpersons (shortened with VP+number)
What would also be great is not only, to get the pronoun but also the line it occurs, in the current code this does unfortunately not work.
I also get an indentation-error, which my colleague workig with the same code doesn't get.

Thank you!

```
import re

    with open (r'./Transliteration_Task1_DE.txt', 'r')as file:

        pro=["ich", "mir", "mich", "wir", "uns", "du", "dir", "dich"]
        t=""    #variable for testpersons
        output=list()
        for line in file:
            words=list()
            words=line.split(" ")
            #print(words)
            if re.match(r'.*VP.*', line):
                t=line
                words=line.split(" ")
                #print(words)
            for w in words:
                #print(w)
                for p in pro:
                    if p == w:
                        print(p, t)
                        output.append([p,t])
        for o in output:
            print(output) #output should be a list with sublists (testpersons and pronouns)
```

Comment: Indentation error is often down to a mix of tabs/spaces.  What text editors are you using?
You only really need to do one loop - you can change `for w in words: for p in pro: if p == w:` to something like `for w in words: if w in pro:`

Comment: Please give an example of what you are expecting

Comment: @Kind Stranger Thank you! I am using Notepad++.  I would like to get an output that says: participant, line in which pro occurs. E.g. VP1, "Ich lege die Banane";

Comment: In which case, you should be able to click the `¶` button to show all characters.  Make sure you use EITHER tabs or spaces (do not mix) and make sure it all lines up.

Comment: If you provide an example input ,output of what you expect. That would be good.

Answer (score 1):

If that is what you want to do, you can *join* two lists using the `+` operator:

```
>>> p = [0, 1]
>>> q = [2, 3]
>>> p + q
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Using the `*` (asterisk) unary operator to unpack elements:

```
>>> [*p, *q]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

And using `.extend()` list method:

```
>>> p.extend(q)
>>> print(p)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified:

```
pronouns = ["ich", "mir", "mich", "wir", "uns", "du", "dir", "dich"]
output = []

with open (r'./Transliteration_Task1_DE.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(file):
        words = line.split()  # Split the line on whitespaces such that words contains a list of words from the line.

        if "VP" in line:  # Only do something if the line contains "VP" - you don't need a regular expression.
            for pronoun in pronouns:  # Search all pronouns
                if pronoun in words:  # If the pronoun is in the list of words, append it to the output
                    print(pronoun, line_number, line)
                    output.append([pronoun, line_number, line])

for o in output:
    print(o)
```

To get the line number, you can just `enumerate` the file handle.

To see whether the line contains the string `VP`, there's a more pythonic way using the `in` operator.

Similarly for the second nested for loop: Just use `in` to see whether the pronoun is contained in the list of words.

Also, it helps to give more readable variable names. One-character names are often confusing and very difficult to read.

Also, keep in mind that your input line may contain punctuation which you might need to remove or uppercase/lowercase combinations. If you want to be case-insensitive, you will need to make all words lowercase (see the `lower` function of `str`).